# Разместить время в таблице

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы время было по центру `border-right`?

```css
.td1 {
 border-right: 1px solid;
 height: 20px;
 border-bottom: 0px;
}
.td2 {
 text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; ">
 <tr style="background: #28a745;">
  <td style="border-right: 1px solid; height: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom: 0px;"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
  <td class="td1"></td>
    <td class="td1"></td>
    <td class="td1"></td>
  <td style="height: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom: 0px;"></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td class="td2">00:00</td>
  <td class="td2">01:00</td>
  <td class="td2">02:00</td>
  <td class="td2">03:00</td>
  <td class="td2">04:00</td>
  <td class="td2">05:00</td>
  <td class="td2">06:00</td>
  <td class="td2">07:00</td>
  <td class="td2">08:00</td>
  <td class="td2">09:00</td>
  <td class="td2">10:00</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, может? 
Не совсем понятно вопрос задаёте...

```css
  .td1 {
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.td1 span {
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.td2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; ">
    <tr style="background: #28a745;">
 <td class="td1" style="height: 20px;"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
        <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
        <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
 <td class="td1"><span></span></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
 <td class="td2">00:00</td>
 <td class="td2">01:00</td>
 <td class="td2">02:00</td>
 <td class="td2">03:00</td>
 <td class="td2">04:00</td>
 <td class="td2">05:00</td>
 <td class="td2">06:00</td>
 <td class="td2">07:00</td>
 <td class="td2">08:00</td>
 <td class="td2">09:00</td>
 <td class="td2">10:00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```